# Entity Framework Object not allowing Connection String to be passed as parameter

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I am trying to initialize an Entity object (ADO.NET EF Object), but it does not allow me to choose what connection string I want to use. I need to change connection string in order to give different access levels to users.

There are no overrides in the Entities Object, just a parameterless constructor.

If anyone can give me any pointers, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used the designer to generate an **.edmx** file for you, you will have something like below:

```
    public MyEntities() : base("name=MyEntities", "MyEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

This will by default, get the connection string from your configuration file.

What you could do in this case is set the connection string

```
    public partial class MyEntities
    {

    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
       //Dynamically Building a Connection String
       this.Connection.ConnectionString = "myconnectionstring";          
    }
   }
```

Bear in mind though that this will first use the base constructor to pull the connection string from config, then set it with your custom version, basically overriding the connection string. This is typically good when you always want a default connection string.

Another option if you want a bit more control, is pass the connection string in via the constructor as shown below:

```
    public partial class MyEntities
    {   
     public MyEntities(string connectionString) :           
     base(connectionString,"MyEntities")       
     {

       this.OnContextCreated();       
    }
   }
```

Now you are passing in the connection string down to the base class and this is the only one it will use. This does mean however that you will most often need to supply this each time.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I followed your tips. Created a new file for the partial class and added this code: public partial class Entities
    {
        public Entities(string connectionString) :
            base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }

Giving it a go.